# WinSCP: How to find the current connected port for both server and client?

Tags: ftp, winscp

I am trying to find out what ports are connected between server and client after an FTP login and data transfer.

Is there some sort of log for it in WinSCP?

Thanks.

Comment: What ports are you looking for? What do you need it for?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am trying to verify if my settings for the ports of FTP server actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check what data connection ports are being used, check entries like this in the [session log file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging):

```
> 2020-02-22 20:01:25.188 PASV
< 2020-02-22 20:01:25.188 227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,221,133)
> 2020-02-22 20:01:25.188 STOR foobar.txt
. 2020-02-22 20:01:25.188 Connecting to 127.0.0.1:56709 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For that you can just use the `netstat` command built into Windows.
Step 1. find process ID of winscp from task manager. or if you prefer, use command `tasklist | findstr WinSCP`
Step 2. Find out local and remote ports using command `netstat -ano | findstr PID-OF-WINSCP`
[image]

Comment: I suppose it is the control connection. Is there a way to find out the data transfer connection?

Comment: You would have to run the `netstat` command during a transfer. Easier is to check the session log file.